# How to grep only the channel number

Tags: debian, grep, terminal, wifi

From :

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Frequency
```

I get

```
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

But I want only output as

```
1
1
11
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest taking a look at some regular expression tutorial first. You can then get what you want using `grep -o`, `sed`, or `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `|awk -F 'Channel' '{print $2}'  |cut -d ')' -f 1` to the command as this:

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Frequency |awk -F 'Channel' '{print $2}' |cut -d ')' -f 1`

awk filter the world "Channel" while with the put you avoid the last **)**.

Comment: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | sed -r -e 's/Frequency.*\(Channel ([0-9]+)\)$/\1/'`